# DATEDIFF formula in powerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, measure

I try to calculate the Time difference (Departure - Arrival) with 2 columns (Date & Time) for each.
I've created a calculated column with the following formula :

```
Time =

VAR _ArrivalDate = Table[ArrivalDate] + Table[ArrivalHour]
VAR _DepartureDate = Table[DepartureDate] + Table[DepartureHour]

RETURN
DATEDIFF(
        _ArrivalDate,
        _DepartureDate,
        HOUR
)
// _DepartureDate - _ArrivalDate
```

It works fine with the formula in Commentary, but i Can't understand why the formula with Datediff fails & returns 00:00 ?  Can someone Help me ?

Comment: Can you post the sample data table showing the issue

Comment: Here is the link : https://1drv.ms/u/s!An2aQoxg76Kv8EwooLVoT8JVy6mI?e=svVto8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DATEDIFF() doesn't return a time. If you change your data type to whole number  or decimal, you get the correct return.

[image]

Note the following:

[image]